# How do i resolve state when service has been failed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

Thanks for reading this question.
I am making AngularJS app.
I made a state and define resolve that is calling User.getProfile which is defined in User service.
so this resolve is working when service has been succeeded to fetch profile but not working when it has been failed.
let me post a code.

```
    .state('app.profile', {
        url: '/profile',
        views: {
            'menuContent': {
                templateUrl: 'views/pages/profile.html',
                controller: 'ProfileCtrl',
            }
        },
        resolve: {
            data: function(User) {
                return User.getProfile();
            }
        }
    })
```

and here is service i defined.

```
service.getProfile = function() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        HttpReq.sendRequest( RESTAPI.DEV_URL + RESTAPI.PROFILE,
            'GET',
            undefined,
            function(result) {
                /*

                */
                if (result.success) {
                    deferred.resolve(result);
                }
                else {
                    deferred.reject(result);

                }

            },
            function(error, response) {
                deferred.reject(error);

                //uiHelper.alert($scope, 'Login Error', response.message);
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    };
```

app.profile is resolved when defer.resolve is called in service.
but isn't resolved when defer.reject is called.
Please correct me if i have problem in promise calling.

Thanks!

Comment: i didn't get it, actually you can retrieve the status by adding the `then` syntax ```User.getProfile().then(successCallback, errorCallback);``` because actually you are returning a promise, i don't know how you will use it

Comment: that's not what i wanted.

Comment: it's not really clar what you want

Comment: resolve will throw data object to profile controller when it's resolved.
That's pointless to use callback while at defining state.
What i want is to throw data object to profile controller for every case in service. for defer.resolve and defer.reject.

Comment: now data object is passed only once defer.resolve is called.
Can i make it passed for defer.reject is called too?

Answer (score 2):

If the resolve function fail, you will probably want to display to the user something accordingly (like an error message). It would be better to let your resolve function return a promise (without then) and use the internal event $routeChangeError.

```
 myApp.run(['$rootScope',function($rootScope) {
  $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeError', function() {
    // what you want to do if an error occurs 
    // ex: $rootScope.displayErrorMessage = true
  });
}]);
```

Comment: good point! but is there an way to change the state regardless of resolve?